# How to make inference on local PC with the model trained on AWS SageMaker by using the built-in algorithm Semantic Segmentation?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, mxnet, gluon

Similar to the issue of [The trained model can be deployed on the other platform without dependency of sagemaker or aws service?](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/issues/200).

I have trained a model on AWS SageMaker by using the built-in algorithm [Semantic Segmentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/semantic-segmentation.html). This trained model named as `model.tar.gz` is stored on S3. So I want to download this file from S3 and then use it to make inference on my local PC without using AWS SageMaker anymore. Since the built-in algorithm Semantic Segmentation is built using the [MXNet Gluon framework and the Gluon CV toolkit](https://github.com/dmlc/gluon-cv), so I try to refer the documentation of [mxnet](https://mxnet.apache.org/) and [gluon-cv](https://gluon-cv.mxnet.io/) to make inference on local PC.

It's easy to download this file from S3, and then I unzip this file to get three files:

1. **hyperparams.json**: includes the parameters for network architecture, data inputs, and training. Refer to [Semantic Segmentation Hyperparameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/segmentation-hyperparameters.html).
2. **model_algo-1**
3. **model_best.params**

Both **model_algo-1** and **model_best.params** are the trained models, and I think it's the output from `net.save_parameters` (Refer to [Train the neural network](https://beta.mxnet.io/guide/getting-started/crash-course/4-train.html)). I can also load them with the function `mxnet.ndarray.load`.

Refer to [Predict with a pre-trained model](https://beta.mxnet.io/guide/getting-started/crash-course/5-predict.html). I found there are two necessary things:

1. Reconstruct the network for making inference.
2. Load the trained parameters.

As for reconstructing the network for making inference, since I have used PSPNet from training, so I can use the class `gluoncv.model_zoo.PSPNet` to reconstruct the network. And I know how to use some services of AWS SageMaker, for example batch transform jobs, to make inference. I want to reproduce it on my local PC. If I use the class `gluoncv.model_zoo.PSPNet` to reconstruct the network, I can't make sure whether the parameters for this network are same those used on AWS SageMaker while making inference. Because I can't see the image `501404015308.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/semantic-segmentation:latest` in detail.

As for loading the trained parameters, I can use the `load_parameters`. But as for **model_algo-1** and **model_best.params**, I don't know which one I should use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works well for me.

```py
import mxnet as mx
from mxnet import image
from gluoncv.data.transforms.presets.segmentation import test_transform
import gluoncv

# use cpu
ctx = mx.cpu(0)

# load test image
img = image.imread('./img/IMG_4015.jpg')
img = test_transform(img, ctx)
img = img.astype('float32')

# reconstruct the PSP network model
model = gluoncv.model_zoo.PSPNet(2)

# load the trained model
model.load_parameters('./model/model_algo-1')

# make inference
output = model.predict(img)
predict = mx.nd.squeeze(mx.nd.argmax(output, 1)).asnumpy()
```